# How can I use CONTAINS() when the variable is sometimes null or empty string?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, full-text-search, contains

I have the following where clause:

```
B.GivenName=@GivenFirstName)  
or ((@GivenFirstName = '""') 
or  (@GivenFirstName is null)) 
or (B.GivenName like +'%'+ @GivenFirstName) 
or (B.GivenName like  @GivenFirstName + '%' )  
or (B.GivenName like + '%'+ @GivenFirstName + '%' ) 
or (CONTAINS(B.GivenName, @GivenFirstName,LANGUAGE 'german'))
```

If a firstname is not entered into the search I get the error:

```
Msg 7645, Level 15, State 2, Procedure Search_test, Line 179
Null or empty full-text predicate.
```

I tried wrapping the @GivenFirstName in

```
COALESCE(@GivenFirstName, '""')
```

but it doesn't work either.

Is  there some way I can use @GivenFirstName OR '""' if @GivenFirstName is null inside the where clause?

Thanks, 
Thomas

Comment: You're missing an opening parenthesis but I assume this is just a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help everyone. I was originally using this so that when accented characters such as é are entered into the search they still return results without accents and vice versa..

I ended up just using a strip accents function like so:

```
(((dbo.fn_StripAccents(B.GivenName)=dbo.fn_StripAccents(@GivenFirstName))  
or ((@GivenFirstName = '""') 
or (@GivenFirstName is null)) 
or (dbo.fn_StripAccents(B.GivenName) like +'%'+ dbo.fn_StripAccents(@GivenFirstName)) 
or (dbo.fn_StripAccents(B.GivenName) like  dbo.fn_StripAccents(@GivenFirstName) + '%' )     
or (dbo.fn_StripAccents(B.GivenName) like + '%'+ dbo.fn_StripAccents(@GivenFirstName) + '%' ))
```

Answer (score 2):

`COALESCE` should do that for you, but you should have `COALESCE(@GivenFirstName, '')` (without the double quotes) on each parameter

Also I dont think you need all these conditions. The `CONTAINS` should do everything for you.

You can do WHERE CONTAINS(B.GivenName, ' "" OR @GivenFirstName ') for example

Also, try reading about the  INFLEXIONAL parameter [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I figured it's quite extensive. It's a 500 line procedure I've taken over from .... a cheap firm from India .... So I'm trying to change as little as possible right now.

Comment: cant you check the parameter in the beginning of the proc and if it is null, make it an empty string?

Comment: Is it normal for contains to drastically increase the query time?

Comment: I've taken out all the extra conditions and changed it to:         (((CONTAINS(B.GivenName,  ' "" OR @GivenFirstName ',LANGUAGE 'german')))
 and it's taking over 3 minutes to query.

Comment: on the contrary. Fulltext search is faster, but in this case you are running CONTAINS with several other LIKES, so it will be slower. If you compare CONTAINS (B.GivenName, "Test" ')  with the b.GivenName like '%Test%', contains will be faster

Comment: try to remove the OR just to see how long does it take

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
WHERE B.GivenName COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AI LIKE 
   '%' + ISNULL(@GivenFirstName, '') COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AI + '%'
```

Changing the collation to case-insensitive, accent-insensitive will do the comparison without the accents on both sides. IsNull will turn the variable into an empty string if it is null, and if it is an empty string, then the search string will be '%%', which basically means 'Starts with anything and ends with anything', so will also return True.